# Pass variable to angularjs directive

Tags: angularjs, variables, directive

I have an angularjs directive element with an external template (url) and controller.

```
app.directive('ngMyDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        templateUrl : 'my-template.html',
        controller : 'MyController'
    }
});
```

This directive is currently used in a couple of views. The html it generates contains a textarea which requires a dynamic number of rows depending on parent view of the directive. Is there a way to pass the directive a variable to set the number of rows dynamically and which can be accessed in both the template and controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the isolate scope syntax and declare a 2 Way binding variable like this scope:{rows:'='} in your directive definition object.This can be used as a normal scope variable in ur link function.to bind this rows to parent directive we will have to create an attribute rows in the directive HTML with value as the scope variable of the parent u want to bind it to
For eg

```
<div ng-controller='parent having       dynamic value totalrows'>
<child-directive rows='totalrows' />
</div>
```